# Ephemeral Identifiers? How to use these?

Tags: google-beacon-platform

We want to prevent piggybacking of our beacons and information by using this feature they said is built in. Ephemeral Identifiers

How is it built in and how do i use it?

I am assuming we could pass this to the proximity API as an authenticated API user and it will return the actual beacon meta data?

Comment: Good question.  Unfortunately, I don't believe this information is available yet.  As of today July 14, 2015, Google's blog says,  "We’ll publish the technical specs of this design soon." -- http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2015/07/lighting-way-with-ble-beacons.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Ryan for your question! I'm Nirdhar and a Product Manager at Google on Privacy/Security working on Ephemeral IDs. As David mentioned above, we will publish the technical spec soon and we're hard at work on it. While I can't provide an official release date, I promise to follow up on this thread with an answer on launch day.

Comment: Landed here following a search. I'm assuming the tech spec is now available. Could you complete your answer?